# Was this 1791 Pennsylvania taxpayer an owner or renter?

Tags: united-states, 18th-century, taxation-records, pennsylvania

In a 1791 tax record for Bedford County, PA, my relative is listed as a single freeman "on hous and lott". Does this mean he owned the property, was renting, or lived with someone else? He would have been 28 years old at the time and was married shortly after.

Answer (score 6):

Tax records only list the owners of a property, unlike census records which list the individuals present at a certain address on a specific day. You can assume that your relative owned the house in question and the land on which it stood.